# NHibernate SchemaUpdate adding existing foreign keys again?

Tags: nhibernate, schema, database-schema

I'm using `SchemaUpdate` to synchronize my `hbms` with existing database. Database has recently created based on `hbms` and is completely up-to-date. But `SchemaUpdate` generates all foreign key constraints again.

For example suppose you have `Student` and `Teacher`. `Student` has association to `Teacher` with name `ArtTeacher`. `ArtTeacher` is a foreign key from `Student` to `Teacher`. Suppose database is up-to-date and currently holde `Student`, `Teacher` and their foreign key relation. So `HBM` and `Database` are equivalent. Know `SchemaUpdate` must not do anything but when I see its generated scripts, it re-produce that foreign key again.

Why this happens? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: I'm getting this too; I have an existing foreign key relationship and running new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(action, false) keeps wanting to regenerate it... I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The secret is to ensure that you specify names for the foreign keys, or else NHibernate will generate a random name which won't match the existing schema.

(I fished this answer out of the Google Cache of Afshar's blog post).